# Using Gravatar in Flask Application

Tags: python, flask, gravatar

I want to use Gravatar to display users' profile pictures in my flask application.
I followed the instructions in the documentation
https://flask-gravatar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

However, when running my application I get this error message:

```
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/ubuntu/finalproject/application.py", line 21, in <module>
gravatar = Gravatar(app,
NameError: name 'Gravatar' is not defined
```

This is the beginning of the main file:

```
import os
import time
import datetime

from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions, HTTPException, InternalServerError
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash


# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

#initialize gravatar
gravatar = Gravatar(app,
                    size=80,
                    rating='g',
                    default='retro',
                    force_default=False,
                    force_lower=False,
                    use_ssl=False,
                    base_url=None)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True
```

At the moment I just want to test how it works. So my test.html just contains:
{{ 'zzz.sochi@gmail.com' | gravatar }}
and is called with GET and render_template.

Can someone tell me what I have to do, that the variable "Gravatar" defined in **init**.py is recognized?

Folder structure:
[Structure in CS50 IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtMAu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example provided in the Gravatar documentation is bad. If you do this:

```
gravatar = Gravatar(app,
                    size=80,
                    rating='g',
                    default='retro',
                    force_default=False,
                    force_lower=False,
                    use_ssl=False,
                    base_url=None)
```

... without `Gravatar` being defined somewhere in your file, it will fail. In this case I think you need:

```
from flask_gravatar import Gravatar

gravatar = Gravatar(...)
```